# How to find a java support of browser

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Java enabled: " + navigator.javaEnabled());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Its work perfect when java is not available in machine. but when i disable java plugins from IE or chrome its still give me a true result (Works perfect in FF).

is there any proper way for finding a java support for page i want to give a custom message to users when java plugin is not available or disable.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at deployJava.js:

http://java.com/js/deployJava.js

http://java.com/js/deployJava.txt